# How to install async/await support in Typescript 3 project?

Tags: typescript, es6-promise, typescript-typings

I have a new Typescript project that I cannot seem to get async/await working in. When I run `tsc src/index.ts --noEmit` I get the following error:

```
$ tsc src/index.ts --noEmit
error TS2468: Cannot find global value 'Promise'.

src/index.ts:130:29 - error TS2705: An async function or method in ES5/ES3 requires the 'Promise' constructor.  Make sure you have a declaration for the 'Promise' constructor or include 'ES2015' in your `--lib` option.

130           gameFS.initialize(async function(e: Error) {
                                ~~~~~


Found 2 errors.
```

I can reproduce this with a simple `index.ts` that looks like:

```
const timer = window.setTimeout(async function (){
  const res = await fetch('./files');
  console.log(res);
}, 0);
```

I am working with the following versions:

```
$ tsc -v
Version 3.9.6
$ node -v
v10.13.0
```

I have tried to install Promises with several different configurations to `tsconfig.json` that I have found around the internet that looks like they have worked for other users. My current `tsconfig.json` looks like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es6",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": ['dom', 'es2015', 'es2016', 'es2017', 'es2015.promise'],
    "declaration": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
  },
  "typeRoots": [
    "node_modules/@types"
  ]
  "include": [
    "src/*"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "tests/*"
  ]
}
```

I have tried all the `lib` values with no success. I have also tried installing a Promise types package `"@types/es6-promise": "^3.3.0"` Not sure what i'm missing here and stumped.

Comment: Are you sure your `tsconfig.json` file is being picked up? I don't usually run `tsc` on single files, but I wonder if it looks for `tsconfig.json` in `src/`

Comment: wow thank you @Evert I think thats the problem. I inherited this configuration as a boilerplate so assumed it was correct.

Comment: FYI, single quoted strings aren't valid in JSON. Some tools may accept it, but may run into issues. Also you can run `tsc --project tsconfig.json src/index.ts`